# Insert comma to a string of numbers after specific numbers of digits

Tags: java, regex, database

I have this number

```
6430134080234080234080200000000
```

and i want it in this form :

```
643,01,340802,340802,340802,00000000
```

My aim is to insert it to a database.

Comment: And what have you tried? SO is no free coding service!

Comment: How are the columns of the `,` determined?  Is it a set column number from the beginning of the number?  Also [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: It is entirely irrelevant what you want to with the "number" after formatting - whether sending it to a mars rover, or putting it in a database.

Comment: I tried something like this : List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
  Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d([,\\s])?\\d\\d([,\\s])?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d([,\\s])?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d([,\\s])?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d([,\\s])?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d([,\\s])?");
  Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(nums2);
  while (regexMatcher.find()) {
      resultList.add(regexMatcher.group());
  }

Comment: @user2456348 Edit your question.

Comment: First i want to separate the number with commas and then with StringTokenizer to split it, to input in database

Comment: Which does not tell _anything_ on what the rules to split a number are to begin with.

Comment: each separated group of digits will be inputed to a different column of my database

Comment: How does this knowledge about "different columns" help us determine the **rules for splitting the string**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you obviously don't have a number, but a string.

```
String s = "6430134080234080234080200000000";
```

You can format it like so:

```
String formatted = s.substring(0,3) + "," + s.substring(3,5) + "," ...
```

Note that this only works if the input string is of the same length.

Comment: This question is a good example of where regex is an unnecessary over-complication, and you're better off without it! (I.e. This answer is the way to go!)